# Verilog: Illegal redeclaration

Tags: verilog

I am attempting to generate a programming file useing ISE 14.7 for some of the benchmarks provided on Trust-Hub.org. I am working with AES-T100 which contains a series verilog files. I have never worked with verilog and haven't touched VHDL in years.

In theory the verilog code provided by trust-hub should work however trying it gives the compile error

```
ERROR:HDLCompilers:27 - "../../../../../../AES-T100/src/TjIn/TSC.v" line 28 Illegal redeclaration of 'load'
```

Now, this error is fairly self explanatory however looking at a beginners verilog tutorial [here](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/syntax2.html) I can see the exact same repetition of variables names.

Does this verilog code below look correct or is there some error in the trust-hub code?

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Company: 
// Engineer: 
// 
// Create Date:    12:20:01 03/06/2013 
// Design Name: 
// Module Name:    TSC 
// Project Name: 
// Target Devices: 
// Tool versions: 
// Description: 
//
// Dependencies: 
//
// Revision: 
// Revision 0.01 - File Created
// Additional Comments: 
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
module TSC(
    input rst,
    input clk,
    input [127:0] key,
    output [63:0] load
    );

    reg [63:0] load;
    wire [19: 0] counter;

    lfsr_counter lfsr (rst, clk, counter);
    always @ (posedge clk)
        begin
            load[0] <= key[0] ^ counter[0]; 
            load[1] <= key[0] ^ counter[0]; 
            load[2] <= key[0] ^ counter[0]; 
            load[3] <= key[0] ^ counter[0]; 
            load[4] <= key[0] ^ counter[0]; 
            load[5] <= key[0] ^ counter[0]; 
            load[6] <= key[0] ^ counter[0]; 
            load[7] <= key[0] ^ counter[0]; 

            load[8] <= key[1] ^ counter[1]; 
            load[9] <= key[1] ^ counter[1]; 
            load[10] <= key[1] ^ counter[1];    
            load[11] <= key[1] ^ counter[1];    
            load[12] <= key[1] ^ counter[1];    
            load[13] <= key[1] ^ counter[1];    
            load[14] <= key[1] ^ counter[1];    
            load[15] <= key[1] ^ counter[1];    

            load[16] <= key[2] ^ counter[2];    
            load[17] <= key[2] ^ counter[2];    
            load[18] <= key[2] ^ counter[2];    
            load[19] <= key[2] ^ counter[2];    
            load[20] <= key[2] ^ counter[2];    
            load[21] <= key[2] ^ counter[2];    
            load[22] <= key[2] ^ counter[2];    
            load[23] <= key[2] ^ counter[2];    

            load[24] <= key[3] ^ counter[3];    
            load[25] <= key[3] ^ counter[3];    
            load[26] <= key[3] ^ counter[3];    
            load[27] <= key[3] ^ counter[3];    
            load[28] <= key[3] ^ counter[3];    
            load[29] <= key[3] ^ counter[3];    
            load[30] <= key[3] ^ counter[3];                
            load[31] <= key[3] ^ counter[3];                

            load[32] <= key[4] ^ counter[4];    
            load[33] <= key[4] ^ counter[4];    
            load[34] <= key[4] ^ counter[4];    
            load[35] <= key[4] ^ counter[4];    
            load[36] <= key[4] ^ counter[4];    
            load[37] <= key[4] ^ counter[4];    
            load[38] <= key[4] ^ counter[4];    
            load[39] <= key[4] ^ counter[4];    

            load[40] <= key[5] ^ counter[5];    
            load[41] <= key[5] ^ counter[5];    
            load[42] <= key[5] ^ counter[5];    
            load[43] <= key[5] ^ counter[5];    
            load[44] <= key[5] ^ counter[5];    
            load[45] <= key[5] ^ counter[5];    
            load[46] <= key[5] ^ counter[5];                
            load[47] <= key[5] ^ counter[5];                

            load[48] <= key[6] ^ counter[6];    
            load[49] <= key[6] ^ counter[6];                
            load[50] <= key[6] ^ counter[6];    
            load[51] <= key[6] ^ counter[6];    
            load[52] <= key[6] ^ counter[6];    
            load[53] <= key[6] ^ counter[6];    
            load[54] <= key[6] ^ counter[6];    
            load[55] <= key[6] ^ counter[6];

            load[56] <= key[7] ^ counter[7];    
            load[57] <= key[7] ^ counter[7];    
            load[58] <= key[7] ^ counter[7];    
            load[59] <= key[7] ^ counter[7];    
            load[60] <= key[7] ^ counter[7];    
            load[61] <= key[7] ^ counter[7];    
            load[62] <= key[7] ^ counter[7];    
            load[63] <= key[7] ^ counter[7];                
        end

endmodule
```

**Edit**
I found this discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37200244/why-does-the-following-redeclaration-error-happen-in-verilog) that talks about the ansi style header.
I changed the top of the module code to this:

```
module TSC(
    input rst,
    input clk,
    input [127:0] key,
     output reg [63:0] load
    );

    //reg [63:0] load;
    wire [19: 0] counter;
```

And it worked. Is the style above that didn't work from older versions of verilog or something? Why would they publish 'tested' code that so clearly doesn't work?

Comment: That 'tested' code is mix of old and ansi style, which may have worked in a version of a simulator, but it is not standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare like this and remove `reg [63:0] load;`

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    module TSC(
    input rst,
    input clk,
    input [127:0] key,
    output reg[63:0] load
    );
```