# verilog cannot index into non-array error?

Tags: verilog

```
module lab2_4bit_adder(
    input [3:0] A,
    inout [3:0] B,                //B=Z
    input C0,
    input [3:0] B1,
    input Switch,
    inout [3:0] B2,
    output [3:0] S,
    output C4
);

wire C1;
wire C2;
wire C3;
wire B;
wire B2;

assign B2 = ~B1 + 1'b1;
assign B = (Switch == 0)? B1:B2;
assign B = (Switch == 1)? B2:B1;
assign B = Switch? B2:B1;

lab2_1bit_adder fa0(A[0], B[0], C0, S[0], C1);
lab2_1bit_adder fa1(A[1], B[1], C1, S[1], C2);
lab2_1bit_adder fa2(A[2], B[2], C2, S[2], C3);
lab2_1bit_adder fa3(A[3], B[3], C3, S[3], C4);




endmodule
```

the error shows:

> cannot index into non-array B

please help me to solve it 
thank you very much

Comment: `B` is declared as a simple wire inside the module. There is no `B[0]` or `B[1]`. In case you mean the module port, use a different name for the wire.

Comment: what if i use 'wire [3:0] B' or delete wire B?

Comment: Why don't you try it out?

Comment: Why did you declare `B` and `B2` twice? And why as `inout`? And why three functionality equivalent assignments to `B`?

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is re-declared the variable `B` as a wire which is not an array. Its a simple wire variable.

So when you are trying to access `B[0]` in this piece of code it is generating an error and saying that `B` is not an array and so you cannot index it. Just remove the re-declarations the code will work fine.

```html
lab2_1bit_adder fa0(A[0], B[0], C0, S[0], C1);
lab2_1bit_adder fa1(A[1], B[1], C1, S[1], C2);
lab2_1bit_adder fa2(A[2], B[2], C2, S[2], C3);
lab2_1bit_adder fa3(A[3], B[3], C3, S[3], C4);
```

Also somehow re-declarations were probably allowed in older versions of Verilog as per [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39898460/verilog-illegal-redeclaration) But no one has clarified it yet in the answer, but you can check the discussion board.

Final code should look like:

```html
module lab2_4bit_adder(
    input [3:0] A,
    inout [3:0] B,                //B=Z
    input C0,
    input [3:0] B1,
    input Switch,
    inout [3:0] B2,
    output [3:0] S,
    output C4
);

wire C1;
wire C2;
wire C3;    //removed all redeclarations

assign B2 = ~B1 + 1'b1;
assign B = (Switch == 0)? B1:B2;
assign B = (Switch == 1)? B2:B1;
assign B = Switch? B2:B1;

lab2_1bit_adder fa0(A[0], B[0], C0, S[0], C1);
lab2_1bit_adder fa1(A[1], B[1], C1, S[1], C2);
lab2_1bit_adder fa2(A[2], B[2], C2, S[2], C3);
lab2_1bit_adder fa3(A[3], B[3], C3, S[3], C4);




endmodule
```